# Is there a method to change multiple strings having same charecter in Java?

Tags: java, replace, transpose

I am developing an application where I have to transpose from one music scale to another.

#### For Example:

cdefgab as gabcdef

## c as g, d as a, e as b, f as c, g as d, a as e b as f

#### using .replace("c","g").replace("d","a").replace("e","b")... ###

### But the output is a error as when the first c is replaced as g , g is replaced by d

Following is the code:

```
    String tune = "cdef gabc";        
    System.out.println(""+tune.replace("c","g")
                                            .replace("d","a")
                                            .replace("g","d"));
```

Current Output:
daef dabd

Required output:
gaef dabg

## I want the the first string 'c' to be as 'g' and not 'd'

Comment: The java way would be to create a `Note` enum with all the notes, add a `transpose(int halfTones)` to it, then have a `Tune` class which contains a collection of notes and has a `transpose(Note from, Note to)` which calls the `transpose` method of each Note with the appropriate parameter.

Comment: unless you take each character (and its position) and convert it, I don't see any efficient solution for this...

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
System.out.println(tune.replace("a", "\uFFFF")
                       .replace("d", "a")
                       .replace("g", "d")
                       .replace("c", "g")
                       .replace("f", "c")
                       .replace("b", "f")
                       .replace("e", "b")
                       .replace("\uFFFF", "e"));
```

note: \uFFFF is not a valid character by definition so it won't appear in a valid string.

Comment: @Peter
thanks, but the output comes in boxes like def ab. i want the first letter 'c' as a 'g' and the fifth letter 'g' as a 'd'. thanks

Comment: @clem Can you say how this is different to the options I gave you?

Comment: @PeterLawrey The second option works fine with just the 3 letters, but since I have to convert cdefgab as gabcdef the prob persists with some other alphabet even if I change the order.

Comment: @clem you have to order them so the letter you are converting to has itself already been converted. See above how I made sure the letter on the right was converted away just before.

Answer (score 3):

Without using replace:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for ( char c : tune ) {
    buf.append( map(c) );
}
```

Then define map(char note) as you wish.

```
private char map( char originalNote ) {
    switch(originalNote) {
        case 'c': return 'g';
        case 'd': return 'a';
        case 'e': return 'b';            
        case 'f': return 'c';
        case 'g': return 'd';
        case 'a': return 'e';
        case 'b': return 'f';
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown note: " + originalNote );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicly your problem is that the replace method does not know that not all "g" characters weren't "g"s in the original string. So you have to find a way to distinguish them. One way to do that is to replace the "g"s with something like "g_" at first and then in a second run replace all "g_"s with "d" so you would do something like that:

```
String tune = "cdef gabc";        
String tune_ = tune.replace("c","c_").replace("d","d_").replace("g","g_"));
System.out.println(tune_.replace("c_","g")
                        .replace("d_","a")
                        .replace("g_","d"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to make it generalized for any scale change:

```
String newStr = "";
char ch;
int incr = 4;    // Scale notes increment

for(int i = 0; i < tune.length(); i++){
    ch = tune.charAt(i);
    if(ch > 96 && ch < 104){     // a to g
        if(ch > (103 - incr)){
            newStr += (char)(ch + (incr - 7));
        }
        else{             
            newStr += (char)(ch + incr);
        }
    }
    else{
        newStr += (char)ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much ! but could you please explain what happens here? I am a new java user. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all see the conflicts. It will not work using replace or regex replaceall, instead doing a workaround, that I not recommend.

c as g, d as a, e as b, f as c, g as d, a as e, b as f

here:

- d -> a and a -> e and e -> b and b -> f and f -> c and c -> g and g -> d

Than, the problem is that still have conflicts replacing g -> d and d -> a.

If you change the conflict order of replacement, like the following:

- a -> e and e -> b and b -> f and f -> c and c -> g and g -> d and d -> a

note that you will still have problem replacing the 'a' character.

You see, the conflicts are circular. If you starting replacing d -> a, and at last a -> e, all of your replacement from d to a and others a will change to a from d. If you invert will have the same trouble.

If there wouldn't conflicts, I will not recommend to use replace method because the complexity is the O(n^k), where n is the length of the string to be replaced and k is the number of replacements you are planing to apply.

The best way to do this with complexity O(n) is read char by char and replace one by one inside a loop:

```
        String output = "";
        for(char ch : "cdef gabc".toCharArray()) {
            if(ch == 'g') output += 'd';
            else if(ch == 'c') output += 'g';
            else if(ch == 'f') output += 'c';
            else if(ch == 'b') output += 'f';
            else if(ch == 'e') output += 'b';
            else if(ch == 'a') output += 'e';
            else if(ch == 'd') output += 'a';
            else output += ch; // in case of spaces and other chars that will not be replaced
        }
        System.out.println(output);
```